# Wait for all the observable with rxjs

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have the following code:

```
this.hubService.sendScopedCommand(Constants.hangarCommands.getHangarsOfPlayer).then((result: ICommand) => {

    let hangars: IHangar[] = result.arguments[0];

    for (let hangar of hangars) {
        this.pieceService.getGroupedPieces(hangar.pieces).subscribe(group => hangar.groupedPieces = group);
    }

    this.hangars$.next(hangars);
}, (ex: any) => this.hangars$.error(ex));
```

So basically, `sendScopeCommand` is sending something through a websocket and the `then` function is executed when a response is received on the websocket. At this point, I get an array of object that I put in `hangars`.

In these objects I have an array of all the pieces the player owns. There could be multiple piece with the same piece type, so I made a function to group them: `getGroupedPieces`. Its code is the following:

```
public getGroupedPieces(pieces: IPiece[]): Observable<IGroupedPiece[]> {
    return Observable
        .from(pieces)
        .groupBy(p => p.pieceTypeId)
        .flatMap(p => p.toArray())
        .map(p => { return <IGroupedPiece>{ amount: p.length, piece: p[0] }; })
        .toArray();
}
```

This code works but I'm pretty sure it's not correct. Indeed, I think that `hangars` is emitted on the observable even before than the observable in the `for` loop are completed.

What I'd like here is to wait for all these observable to complete before emitting `hangars` on the Observable.

Comment: Why not emit the event when the subscribe is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try to use RxJS's `forkJoin` operator:

```
this.hubService.sendScopedCommand(Constants.hangarCommands.getHangarsOfPlayer).then((result: ICommand) => {

    let hangars: IHangar[] = result.arguments[0];
    let hangars$$: Observable<IHangar>[] = hangars.map(hangar => {
      return this.pieceService.getGroupedPieces(hangar.pieces)
    })

    Observable
      .forkJoin(...hangars$$)
      .subscribe(groups => {
        groups.forEach((group, i) => hangars[i].groupedPieces = group)
        this.hangars$.next(hangars);
      })

}, (ex: any) => this.hangars$.error(ex));
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I try to call subscribe as little as possible and especially avoid possible nesting of subscriptions.

I threw together a quick angular component to give a sample of how I would handle it.

Sorry if it's crude or bad spelling (broken collar bone only one hand to work with.)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

interface hangar {
    pieces: number[];
    groupedPieces: number[];
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app works!';
    //output mock
    hangars$: Subject<hangar[]> = new Subject<hangar[]>();

    ngOnInit() {
        //proof of functionality
        this.hangars$.subscribe(h => console.log(h));
    }

    //method to mock the then call from example
    start() {

        //mock some data
        let hangars: hangar[] = [{ pieces: [1, 2, 3], groupedPieces: null }, { pieces: [1, 2, 3], groupedPieces: null }, { pieces: [1, 2, 3], groupedPieces: null }];

        //subject to handle observable clean up
        let subManagement$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
        let obsArr: Observable<number[]>[] = [];

        //here were going to build an array the observables but not subscribe to them yet
        hangars.forEach(hangar =>
            obsArr.push(
                this.getGroupedPieces(hangar.pieces)
                    .takeUntil(subManagement$)
                    .do(group => hangar.groupedPieces = group)
            )
        );

        //real magic, this waits for all of the observables responses before emitting its value
        Observable.combineLatest(obsArr).subscribe(
            () => this.hangars$.next(hangars),
            null,
            () => subManagement$.next()//cleanup 
        );
    }

    //mock your service
    private getGroupedPieces(pcs: number[]): Observable<number[]> {

        return Observable.of([1, 2, 3, 4]).delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you change Observable to promises you can use `Promise.all` to wait all promises response and continue.